# How to close automatically a opened vtk's window?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

How to avoid that vtk's renderization window appears? What happens is that I use the widget from QVTKWidget and because it i don't need anymore the window created from vtk to rendering the image but I can't to cut some points where I think this window will disappear because it influences on the image that widget loads.
I already tried somethings like use vtkobject destructors like Delete() and method to clear the vtkRenderWindowInteractor like SetRenderWindow(NULL) but none of them works. To simplifying, how to close automatically a opened vtk window?

[image: Snapshot]

*"Rendering Window" is the window created by vtk and behind it "Application" is the window from my application.

*"Rendering Window" only will be closed when "Application" ends.

Comment: the image of the problem http://i.stack.imgur.com/DkOYl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Under MS Windows, vtkRenderWindow::Finalize() works for me...

Answer (score 0):

The QVTKWidget is derived from a QWidget, and you should use the standard methods Qt makes available. When using the QVTKWidget you are actually using Qt's event loop. Did you try calling close on the QVTKWidget?